# How to set up Header/Lines in WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, master-detail

Do you have any best practices for setting up Header/Lines forms (Also known as Header/Details) in WPF or Silverlight?  Preferably using the Mode-View-ViewModel design Pattern to fit in with the rest of my application.

An example would be if I had a grid that displayed all SalesOrders in the database, and the underneath that a grid that showed all of the SalesOrderDetails (The individual lines for the sales order...each item sold) for the selected sales order in the top grid.

I realize I could do this in the code behind file on the Grid's SelectionChanged event, but I'd prefer a declarative way of doing so...in all XAML and ViewModel code.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header/Lines sounds a lot like the Master - Detail pattern to me.  To implement something like this using MVVM is quite simple.

If we were to create a structure where we had a MasterViewModel and a DetailViewModel then in our MasterViewModel we would simply need a property to represent our list of Details and the current Detail.  In the View we can bind a list's ItemSource to the collection of Details and bind the SelectedItem to the CurrentDetail property.  We can then have a seperate View, as a DataTemplate or UserControl, that represents the CurrentDetail and displays our values in the detail grid.

There's also some good resources out there on implementing a Master Detail pattern XAML.

Bea Stollnitz has two excelent samples using XML for the Data Sources: [Here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=13) and [Here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=51).

There's a [MSDN video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/dd239277.aspx) on implementing the pattern in WPF.  (The video is in VB but the code can be downloaded in C#).

In this [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7583cf8c-f54a-4bcb-96ea-0d90681797ea) discussion Johnny Q. demonstrates a simple Master-Detail settup using MVVM.

A lot of [Karl Shifflett's](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/ocean-for-silverlight-enables-sharing-business-objects-with-wpf/) examples also end up demonstrating the Master-Detail pattern, though the code is usually in VB (however some examples come with both C# and VB code.)